# sveltekit no response from page.server

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

on my previous project i use below code for register user and it work fine and now i use it in new project i got error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

it look like +page.server.js return empty string that cause an error

on +page.server.js it working fine except return part

cause it can add a new user to database

Any suggestion?

+page.svelte

```
<script>
import { send } from '$lib/api';

export let error;
export let success;

async function register(event) {
    error = '';
    const formEl = event.target;
    const response = await send(formEl);
    if (response.error) {
        error = response.error;
    }
    if (response.success) {
        success = response.success;
    }
    formEl.reset();
}
</script>
<form on:submit|preventDefault={register} method="post" autocomplete="off">
       ......
</form>
```

api.js

```
export async function send(form) {
const response = await fetch(form.action, {
    method: form.method,
    body: new FormData(form),
    headers: { accept: 'application/json' },
});
return await response.json();
}
```

+page.server.js

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { db } from '$lib/database';

export const POST = async ({ request }) => {
    const form = await request.formData();
    const username = form.get('username').trim();
    const password = form.get('password').trim();

    if (typeof username !== 'string' ||
        typeof password !== 'string') {
        return {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                error: 'Something went horribly wrong.',
            },
        };
    }

    if (!username || !password) {
        return {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                error: 'Username and password is required.',
            },
        };
    }

    try {
         await db.user.create({
             data: {
                 username,
                 passwordHash: await bcrypt.hash(password, 10),
             },
         });
        return {
            status: 200,
            body: { success: 'Success.' }
        };
    }
    catch (error) {
        return {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                error: 'User already exists.',
            },
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to migrate the endpoints to [the new format](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5774#discussioncomment-3292699).

> POST, PUT and PATCH handlers should not return data. They can return an `errors` object of validation errors that can be used for UI (provided to the component as an errors prop), plus an optional status that defaults to 400 when error is provided and is otherwise ignored [...]

So `body` has to be replaced with `errors` and you can no longer return data like `{ success: 'Success.' }`.